# asp.net network security and connectivity

Tags: asp.net

Hello everyone how u doing? I have a problem with my application. When i click on the pages it works find with no error, when i login with my login name and try to browse on the pages, i get this error :

```
Server Error in '/living_to_please_god_world' Application.
The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /living_to_please_god_world/PhotoAdmin/PhotoAdmin/forum.aspx
```

Why is there 2 PhotoAdmin folder instead of 1?
Please help

Comment: You should post a sample of your code if you want to have a better chance that your question will be answered

Comment: Praise the LORD Collins!

Comment: Put a sample of your code here, I am sure there are many people who can help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which authentication method you are using.

But the source of the problem is probably rights to the aspx page. When you are not logged in you are in the security context of one user, when you are logged in you are in the security context of another.

My guess would be that NETWORK SERVICE has access to the file, but the user you are logging in with does not.

Comment: It is not authentication. Error is 404 and not 401.

Comment: @Aliostad, you are correct, but the only difference between the scenarios is the authentication, and the error messages are not always correct.

Comment: Sure, they do happen. It is just that I am used to take things at about face until proven otherwise.